Stuck on loading parquet files recursively of varying size with Spark
I am using Spark on Scala via and Almond kernel for Jupyter to load several parquet files with varying size. I have a single worker with 10 cores and memory allowance of 10GB. When I execute the command:
val df  = spark.read.format("parquet")
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
    .load("/main/parquet")

The memory seems to explode and I get this error:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.6 in stage 2.0 (TID 13) (172.21.0.2 executor 3): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:64)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:363)
    at org.apache.parquet.bytes.HeapByteBufferAllocator.allocate(HeapByteBufferAllocator.java:32)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutivePartList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1842)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.internalReadRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:990)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:940)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextFilteredRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:1082)
...

Inside of the `main/parquet` folder, the parquet files are scattered in an irregular subfolder structure.


Does this already load the files incrementally? Is there a more memory efficient way to accomplish this?
